# Have a German Aufenhaltstitel, overstayed more than 90 days in another Schengen country?

Tags: eu, residency

Is there anyway for border control Polizei to check if I overstayed in another EU country? I was staying with a friend for more than 90 days for reasons undisclosed and I am returning back to Germany next week.

I was just wondering if there's any direct way to know if somebody has overstayed their 90 days outside of Germany? (I am a third country person with a resident permit/aufenhaltstitel).

Comment: It's unlikely they would know unless they had some reason to investigate your movements.

Comment: thanks - in general, they don't 'mark' you when you cross borders if you have a residency anyway right? it's just my paranoia working I guess...

Comment: When you cross internal Schengen borders nobody gets marked, resident or otherwise.